# How to search though a long list of javascript objects to find the first instance of 'sent: 0'

Tags: javascript

Having a major looping problem here.

My data looks like this:

```
var mailouts =
   { signUp: { date: '', sent: 1 },
     lesson1: { sent: 1, time: 20 },
     lesson2: { sent: 0, time: 20 },
     lesson3: { sent: 0, time: 20 },
     lesson4: { sent: 0, time: 20 },
     lesson5: { sent: 0, time: 20 } 
     }
```

I need to go through the `mailouts` object to find which `lesson` is next to be sent (aka which is the first instance of `sent: 0` when going through the lessons in order). I don't have control over the data structure so I need to work with this model.

The only way I can think of is really ugly and unmanageable (there are actually about 50 'lesson' objects, not just 5, just kept it short for brevity.).

The only thing I can think of that will vaguely work is something like this:

```
if(mailouts.lesson1.sent === 1){
    if(mailouts.lesson2.sent === 1){
        if(mailouts.lesson3.sent === 1){
            if(mailouts.lesson4.sent === 1){
                if(mailouts.lesson5.sent === 1){
                    // Everything has been sent
                }else{
                    // Send lesson5
                }
            }else{
                // Send lesson4
            }
        }else{
            // Send lesson3
        }
    }else{
        // Send lesson2
    }
}else{
    // Send lesson1
}
```

Surely Javascript must have an easier way to deal with this, but I'm drawing blanks. Any ideas?

EDIT: just to clarify, I only need to send one 'lesson' every time this script runs - only whichever one comes next in the list.

Comment: It seems like `.lesson1` - `.lesson5` should be in an array so you could just iterate through a single array and find the next one to send with one simple loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code handles dealing the the lessons in order -- even if they aren't in order in the object.  Iterating object properties does NOT guarantee any kind of order, so you must enforce than itself.

```
var mailouts =
   { signUp: { date: '', sent: 1 },
     lesson1: { sent: 1, time: 20 },
     lesson2: { sent: 0, time: 20 },
     lesson3: { sent: 0, time: 20 },
     lesson4: { sent: 0, time: 20 },
     lesson5: { sent: 0, time: 20 } 
     }

var firstLessonWithNoSent;

for (var lessonNum = 0; lessonNum < 50; lessonNum++) {
  var lesson = mailouts["lesson" + lessonNum];

  if (lesson && lesson.sent === 0) {
    firstLessonWithNoSent = lesson;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Running this in my Chrome console, `firstLessonWithNoSent` returns `undefined`...

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it clear: You're using plain JavaScript object so **you cannot be sure about the order** of elements when you're iterating it. It would be much better if they were an array.

If we're dealing with an object, you could use `for .. in` loop like this:

```
for (var lesson in mailouts) {
    if (mailouts.hasOwnProperty(lesson)) {
        if (lesson.sent === 0) {
            // there it is!
        }
    }
}
```

But again, you're dealing with sequential data so **using an object doesn't make any sense**. You should be using an array instead. So it could look like this:

```
var mailouts = [
    { date: '', sent: 1 },
    { sent: 1, time: 20 },
    { sent: 0, time: 20 },
    { sent: 0, time: 20 },
    { sent: 0, time: 20 },
    { sent: 0, time: 20 }
];
```

If we have an array then the solution depends on the environment You can use ES6 `Array.prototype.find` if that's implemented:

```
mailouts.find(function (el) {
    return el.sent === 0;
});
```

if not, a simple `forEach` will suffice:

```
mailouts.forEach(function (el) {
    if (el.sent === 0) {
        // there it is!
    }
});
```

Comment: OP: " I don't have control over the data structure so I need to work with this model."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` keyword to iterate over the attributes of an object:

```
var result = null;
for (lesson in mailouts) {
  if (lesson.indexOf("lesson") == 0 && mailouts[lesson].sent === 0) {
    result = mailouts[lesson];
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This comes close -- but if the OP means `first` by `lowest #` then you can't guarantee you'll go through the properties in order.

Comment: You are assuming there are no other properties on the mailouts object beside lesson numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the properties of the object using array notation to do it dynamically. Something like this:

```
var lessonToSend = null;
for (var i = 1; i < maxLessons; ++i) {
    if (mailouts['lesson' + i].sent !== 1) {
        lessonToSend = mailouts['lesson' + i];
        break;
    }
}
if (lessonToSend !== null) {
    .... send ....
}
```

Also, whoever designed this data structure was an idiot. Lessons should have been an array.