# Looping through a Javascript array of objects to find the first entry that meets a certain condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing an email auto-responder that sends 'lessons' to members. The lessons need to be sent in sequential order. I log this in an array of objects called `mailouts`:

```
 var obj = {
     mailouts:         [ 
        {name: 'signUp', date: '', sent: 1 },
        {name: 'lesson1', sent: 1, time: 11 },
        {name: 'lesson2', sent: 1, time: 11 },
        {name: 'lesson3', sent: 1, time: 11 },
        {name: 'lesson4', sent: 1, time: 11 },
        {name: 'lesson5', sent: 0, time: 11 },
        {name: 'lesson6', sent: 0, time: 11 },
        {name: 'lesson7', sent: 0, time: 11 }
    ]
  }
```

**I need to loop through the list above and return the first object whose `sent === 0`.**

I can loop through the list easily enough with:

```
 for(var i = 0; i<obj.mailouts.length; i++){
    if(obj.mailouts[i].sent === 0){
       var nextLessonToSend = obj.mailouts[i];
    }
 }
```

however this obviously doesn't work if there's more than one item with `sent === 0` because it just returns the last in the sequence.

The condition is that **the code must always return the lowest-numbered object no matter what**. That is, here it should return `lesson5` and never anything else. The array will always be in this order so that's probably easy enough.

Comment: Use the `break` statement to stop the loop when the condition is met

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of a previous question -- some of the answers do just that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127074/how-to-search-though-a-long-list-of-javascript-objects-to-find-the-first-instanc/23127233#23127233

Comment: Add "break;" after you assign the variable to exit your loop.

Comment: Good point @JeremyJStarcher, my actual issue is a little more complex so I'll post it in another question, this one is moot.

Comment: @Jascination: Update your question to reflect what you're actually asking. Don't post another.

Comment: @cookiemonster Alright, figured that because there were answers it'd be better as a new question

Comment: Better yet, search for the answer first. It sound like you want to break an outer loop from an inner one. If that's the case, this is a common scenario so you should have no trouble finding an answer.

Comment: BTW -- My answer in that thread does pay attention to order and should return the lowest number `sent ==0`.  I was very mindful of that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var nextLessonToSend = null;
for(var i = 0; i<obj.mailouts.length; i++){
    if(obj.mailouts[i].sent === 0){
       nextLessonToSend = obj.mailouts[i];
       break;
    }
}
if (nextLessonToSend) {
    //whatever
}
```

should do the trick. Mind the `break`!

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) can be used for what you need.  It will iterate the array and terminate when the first lesson with a sent property equal to `0` is found.

```
var nextLessonToSend;
obj.mailouts.some(function (mail) {
  var isNextLesson = mail.sent === 0;
  if (isNextLesson) nextLessonToSend = mail;
  return isNextLesson;
});
```

Note that `some` was added with ES5 so it is important to consider what your platforms are and how to handle it if they do not have `some` (consult the MDN link to learn more).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` to exit the `for` loop when you match your condition:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < obj.mailouts.length; i++){
    if (obj.mailouts[i].sent === 0) {
       var nextLessonToSend = obj.mailouts[i];
       break;
    }
 }
```

If you have a `for` loop within a `for` loop, you need to use a variable to keep track of if the inner condition has been matched (or play with the loop condition):

```
var found = false,
    thingLookingFor;

for (var i = 0; i < something.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < other.length; i++) {

    if (something === true) {
      thingLookingFor = ...;
      found = true;
      break;
    }      
  }

  if (found) {
    break;
  }
}
```

You can use the loop condition to simplify the above code:

```
var lesson;

for (var j = 0; !lesson && j < something.length; j++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.mailouts.length; i++) {
    if (obj.mailouts[i].sent === 0) {
      lesson = obj.mailouts[i];
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

You have to be careful that `!lesson` evaluates to true when it is set to your expected value. In the provided example, it'll work correctly.

It is worth considering how to refactor your code to avoid a for loop within a for. Another good idea is to try [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [Lo-dash](http://lodash.com/) as both provide functions that make common things in JavaScript easier. Of course, they have an expense of more lines of code but both are on the small side (and if it really is a problem, you could extract the functions you need out of them or use the Google Closure compiler which would eliminate dead code).

MDN: [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)

Comment: Don't know why you're getting downvoted for the correct answer. I actually have this `for` loop within another `for` loop that loops through each of my users' records, will `break` break that loop too? I only want it to break the last `for` loop.

Comment: @Jascination I'm not sure -- voting here is often silly. Eugen and I answered this at the same time. Both right. I've updated my answer with how to break out of a for loop within a for loop.

Comment: @Jascination To be clear, a `break` will only exit the immediate for loop it is inside. So if you break on an inner for loop, the outer will continue. It is easy to try these things so I encourage you to open a console or go to JSFiddle and try things out.

Comment: @Cymen: You can break the outer loop by giving it a label like `MY_OUTER_LOOP: for (var i...`, then giving the label to the `break` statement, like `break MY_OUTER_LOOP;`. No need to use a variable as a flag.

Comment: @cookiemonster Not sure I like that though -- that smells bad to me too. I would just refactor out a loop personally. Good to know though!